# Why does another variable change in AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, getjson, javascript-objects

I have a AngularJS controller like below:

```
schedule.controller('schedule', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/zt-api/business/admin/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]).success(function(data){
        $scope.admin_times = data;
        $scope.admin_times_unix = data;
        $scope.weekDays = {'Saturday': "شنبه", 'Sunday': "یکشنبه", 'Monday': "دوشنبه", 'Tuesday': "سه شنبه",
            'Wednesday': "چهارشنبه", 'Thursday': "پنجشنبه", 'Friday': "جمعه"};
        angular.forEach($scope.admin_times, function (value, key) {
            angular.forEach(value, function (value2, key2) {
                angular.forEach(value2, function (value3, key3) {
                    angular.forEach(value3, function (value4, key4) {
                        angular.forEach(value4, function (value5, key5) {
                            var info = $scope.admin_times[key]["week_"+ key][key3].times[key5];
                            if (!isNaN(info)){
                                var myObj = $.parseJSON('{"date_created":"'+ $scope.admin_times[key]["week_"+ key][key3].times[key5] +'"}'),
                                myDate = new Date(1000*myObj.date_created);
                                $scope.admin_times[key]["week_"+ key][key3].times[key5] = myDate.toLocaleString().split(", ")[1]
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}]);
```

I change `$scope.admin_times`, but I don't know why `$scope.admin_times_unix` also changes!
Can you help me?

Comment: angular.forEach(value4, function (value5, key5) >> you for sure need to improve your code style)

Answer (score 5):

Because you are assigning same reference of `data` to `admin_times` as well as `admin_times_unix` object.

That's why changing in one object is, affecting other object.

You could solve this issue by using `angular.copy` which does create a new reference rather than assigning its actual reference.

```
$scope.admin_times_unix = angular.copy(data);
```